# update figure add hline with sliders Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Hello guys i need help i have a piece of code that adds a list of horizontal lines to a Plotly figure in python. i want to change the code to were we will use a slider to add the horizontal lines to the figure and relayout it. As the slider moves right more horizontal lines will be added to the figure when the slider moves left the horizontal lines will be removed from the figure. Below is the bit of my code so far

```
for v in range(len(sortadlist)):
        fig.add_hline(y=sortadlist[v][0], line_color='brown', line_width=1.5, row=1, col=1)
        fig.add_shape(type="rect",
                      y0=round(sortadlist[v][0],2)-.3, y1=round(sortadlist[v][0],2)+.3, x0=-1, x1=len(df),
                      fillcolor="darkcyan",
                      opacity=0.15)
```

All the code above does is loop through a list of numbers and uses the fig.add_hline to add the horizontal line to the figure. I need help creating a slider that will add the horizontal lines to the figure
[image]

This is how the figure currently looks i want a slider to help with adding more horizontal lines to the figure and remove them also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the entire code is not available, the sample data was handled by obtaining the company's stock price. First of all, horizontal lines and shapes do not have a show/hide attribute, so they are not compatible with sliders. So I have created a code to draw a line according to the appropriate price list in the line chart of the scatter chart. Once the line chart is hidden, the first line chart is made visible.
The structure of the graph is a candlestick with 6 lines and the candlestick is always displayed. A loop process is used to create a list of lines to be shown or hidden.

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df = yf.download("AAPL", start="2022-01-01", end="2023-01-01", progress=False)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

pricelist = np.arange(130,190,10)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                             open=df['Open'],
                             high=df['High'],
                             low=df['Low'],
                             close=df['Close'],
                             name='AAPL'
                            )
             )

fig.add_hrect(y0=df['Close'].median()-10,
              y1=df['Close'].median()+10, 
              annotation_text="Median+-10",
              annotation_position="top right",
              fillcolor="darkcyan",
              opacity=0.25,
              line_width=0)

for p in pricelist:
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                             y=[p]*len(df['Date']),
                             line_color='blue',
                             name=str(p),
                             showlegend=False,
                             visible=False,
                            )
                 )
fig.data[1].visible = True

steps = []
for i in np.arange(1,len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Price lines: " + str(pricelist[i-1])}],
        label=str(pricelist[i-1])
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][0] = True
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Price: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.update_layout(height=600, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting can I add annotations to the left side like it shown on the picture above?

Comment: It is only to indicate that the string can be annotated in a different position and can be displayed on the left side with `annotation_position='top left'`.

Comment: how would i make the hrect change as the price and line changes for example when price is 130 the hrect would be y0 = 130 - .30 and y0 = 130 + .30? please help thanks

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments of my answer, adding a rectangle does not allow you to control whether it is displayed or not, so you cannot switch it by slider values.

Comment: Is there any other similar thing i could do similar to a rectangle shape that would be control with the slider?